# I have been working to achieve bottom navigation with color change in menu when clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-bottomnav

Trying to achieve color change in menu  when clicked buttom navigation items.

here is my xml code

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/button_navigation"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/button_navigation">
    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
```

here is my activity code

```
viewBinding.navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {

            R.id.homeBottom->{
                addFragment(HomeFragment(),false)

            }
            R.id.notificationBottom->{

            }
            R.id.messageBottom->{

            }
            R.id.accountBottom -> {
                addFragment(UserProfileFragment(), false)
            }
        }
        false
    }
```

Any suggestion will be Appreciated .Thank you

Comment: facing problem .
1. every time first menu is clicked by default .
2. when i select other icon in buttomNavigation the color of icon doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is here

```
viewBinding.navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
         ...
        }
        false
    }
```

Use `true` instead of `flase`

> `boolean` **true to display the item as the selected item and false if
> the item should not be selected.** Consider setting non-selectable items
> as disabled preemptively to make them appear non-interactive.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches here as per your question:

1.) If you want to set a default 'colorPrimary' when you click on icon  then just replace return **true** instead of flase inside **setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener**

and remove  two lines from XML

```
app:itemTextColor="@color/button_navigation"
app:itemIconTint="@color/button_navigation"
```

and

2.) For different color you have to create a *selector color* file. so
create a directory **color** in **res** and make a **navigation_color.xml** file
like:

> **res/color/navigation_color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/pink" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/grey_app"/>
</selector>
```

and use this inside to **BottomNavigationView**

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/navigation_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/navigation_color">
    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
```